# Android referrals are missing in Google Play Referral Flow & Sources tabs

Tags: android, google-analytics

I've integrated campaign tracking into my app according to 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#google-play-implement

I tested it and it works, I get: 
I/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Campaign found: utm_source=testSource

But I don't see any campaign data in Google Analytics. Neither Play Referral Flow nor Sources tabs contain any data related to my campaigns. My links look like this: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.application&referrer=utm_source%3Dmy_source%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_term%3Ddownload%252Bbefore%252Bstart%26utm_content%3Dbannerlink

What am I missing?